# Merge unsigned commits with master

Tags: git, github, gpg-signature

I have some unsigned commits in the branch "dev" of my project.

But there was a change in the project and now I have to sign every commit before merging with master.

How could I merge with master if I have commits unsigned in "dev" branch?.

Answer (score 2):

> I have some unsigned commits in the branch "dev" of my project.

You answered your own question:

> …I have to sign every commit…

You have to sign every commit in the branch `dev`. Please be warned that signing a commit changes the entire branch after that commit so at the end you have to force-push the branch `dev`. And make a backup before starting.

Start with the `dev` branch:

```
git checkout dev
```

If there are only few commits in it (starting from the commit where it was branched off of `master`) then you can do `git rebase -i $COMMIT_ID` and run `git commit -S --amend` for every commit you want to sign.

If there are more than just a few you better use `filter-branch`:

```
git filter-branch -f --commit-filter 'git commit-tree -S "$@"' $COMMIT_ID..dev
```

`$COMMIT_ID` is the ID of commit where `dev` was split from `master`. You can find it with `git log --all --decorate` or `git merge-base --fork-point master`.

After signing merge to `master` and push the new `dev`:

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
git push origin master +dev
```